# find dropdown by attribute disabled false

Tags: jquery

I have same dropdown many times in my file like:

```
<select style="width:40%;" name="article[subsection_id]" id="article_subsection_id" class="article_subsection_cls" disabled="disabled"><option value=""></option>
```

I want to find dropdown by class `article_subsection_cls` or id `article_subsection_id` and attribute `disabled` is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [`:not()` pseudo selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('select#article_subsection_id:not([disabled="disabled"]),select.article_subsection_cls:not([disabled="disabled"])')
```

---

If disabled property updated dynamically in that case use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method

```
$('select.article_subsection_cls,select#article_subsection_id').filter(function(){ return !this.disabled; })
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case there is only one element use `id` selector

```
$('#article_subsection_id:not([disabled="disabled"])')
```

---

Or you can use **[`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)** selector

> Although their resulting selections are usually the same, :enabled selector is subtly different from :not([disabled]); :enabled selects elements that have their boolean disabled property strictly equal to false, while :not([disabled]) selects elements that do not have a disabled attribute set (regardless of its value).

```
$('#article_subsection_id:enabled')
```

Comment: @Udaykumardas :  glad to help

Comment: @Udaykumardas : inside the same element

Comment: `$('select.article_subsection_cls').filter(function(){ return !this.disabled; }).find('[value="something"]')` or `$('select.article_subsection_cls:enabled [value="something"]')`

Comment: Actually i am getting the select element by using `$('select.article_subsection_cls').filter(function(){ return !this.disabled; })[0]` code.And want to set an option selected by value.

Comment: @Udaykumardas : yup, what you need to do with that ?

Comment: want to loop all options of this dropdown.

Comment: @Udaykumardas : you want to iterate the options of enabled select tag ? then `$('select.article_subsection_cls:enabled option').each(function(){/* code here */})`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:not(:disabled)` for selecting an element having `"disabled=false"`

```
$('#article_subsection_id:not(:disabled)')
```

Read more about [:not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:enabled](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector ,

```
var elements = $('#article_subsection_id:enabled,.article_subsection_cls:enabled');
```